# How do you reference a variable inside the view and a string directly after?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using razor for the engine and need some clarification on displaying some text directly after a variable (without any space).

**Example Code:**

```
<p>@variable some text</p>
```

The above code will work just fine, but what if I wanted to have some text displayed directly after it without combining it into the variable and without any space between them.

**Obviously this doesn't work:**

```
<p>@variablesometext</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parentheses:

```
<p>@(variable)sometext</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be a simple answer.. just a matter of knowing the syntax.